# HttpWebRequest Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net, exception, httpwebrequest

I am making an asyncronous HttpWebRequest and if that fails, I want to call a backup web service. Like so:

```
public void CallService1()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://MyFirstWebService")
    request.BeginGetResponse(this.CallService1Completed, request);
}

public void CallService1Completed(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result))
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {   
                // Use Data 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        if (?????)
        {
            CallBackupService2();
        }
    }
}
```

Bearing in mind that this is a mobile applications where you may not always have an internet connection. I do not want to call the backup service if there is no internet connection. I only want to call the backup service if the first service is down for some reason. What would I put in the 'IF' statement above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented like:

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
   CallBackupService2();
}
```

Comment: As I understand it we are recommended to try a HttpWebRequest rather than trying to make this call because, this is a blocking call. Is there no way to get this information via the WebException which would be quicker too.

Comment: The WebException.Status field can also be used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx